# Pandas, count common occurences with reference when reference changes on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I Have a table, here's an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],'RefID':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,8,8,8,8,8],"Options":[["A","B","C","D","E"] , ["A","B","C","D","E"] , ["A","B","C","D","E"] , ["D","B","C"] , ["A","B","D","F","G"] , ["D","A","C","G"] , ["G","C","D","A","P"] , ["D","B","C"] , ["A","B","D","F","G"] , ["D","A","C","G"] , ["G","C","D","A","P"] , ["A","C","D"]]})
```

Each row has an ID, and for each ID there is a selected reference ID.
I need to calculate for each row the number of common occurrences between the "Options" value and the "Options" value for the relevant RefID.
Any easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

I Have a solution that works, but there must be a better way to do this...

```
#Iterates the RefID in each row, and appends its options to a list, then add list as column
temp_list=[]
for row in df['RefID']:
    temp_list.append(df["Options"].loc[row])
df["RefOptions"]=temp_list

#Iterates every row and checks the intersection of 'Options' and 'RefOptions'
temp_list=[]
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    temp_list.append(len(list(set(row['Options']).intersection(row['RefOptions']))))
df["CountOutOfRef"]=temp_list
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way: first create a mapping dictionary by setting `ID` as index and selecting `Options` column then iterate over the pairs of id and refid and yank the corresponding options using dict lookup and use set intersection to get common elements

```
d = df.set_index('ID')['Options']
df['count'] = [len(set(d[x]) & set(d[y])) for x, y in zip(df['ID'], df['RefID'])]
```

---

```
    ID  RefID          Options  count
0    1      2  [A, B, C, D, E]      5
1    2      2  [A, B, C, D, E]      5
2    3      2  [A, B, C, D, E]      5
3    4      2        [D, B, C]      3
4    5      2  [A, B, D, F, G]      3
5    6      2     [D, A, C, G]      3
6    7      2  [G, C, D, A, P]      3
7    8      8        [D, B, C]      3
8    9      8  [A, B, D, F, G]      2
9   10      8     [D, A, C, G]      2
10  11      8  [G, C, D, A, P]      2
11  12      8        [A, C, D]      2
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there an easier solution if the table were to be in a long form instead of wide form? (With ID and Ref columns repeating themselves for each of the options...)